What French movie featured a character repeatedly sent back to a fantasy land?
I watched a French movie that must have been made within the last 5 years. The main character was frequently pulled back and forth between the present time, to a medieval land.

The main character restored paintings.
He lost his job when his studio flooded.
When time traveling, he was sucked through the floor or couch.
He frequently returned to the present day, and researched how to battle or engineering skills.
The main character eventually became an emperor of the medieval land.

Does anyone know what film this is?

It's Les Deux Mondes with Benoit PoelVoorde.
The "sucked" through the floor image scene:

The French Synopsis on WikiPedia:

Dans un monde parallèle à trois Soleils, dans le village de Bégameni,
  une petite tribu vit sous l'oppression d'un tyran nommé Zotan. Elle
  attend depuis longtemps que la prophétie se réalise et qu'un sauveur,
  venu d'un autre monde, vienne leur redonner leur liberté.
Au même moment, à Paris, dans notre monde, Rémy Bassano est un simple
  restaurateur d'œuvres d'art discret et sans histoires. Il est marié à
  Lucile avec laquelle il a eu deux enfants.
Un jour, alors que son atelier se retrouve complètement inondé et
  qu'il cherche désespérément à sauver tout ce qui peut l'être, il est
  aspiré et se retrouve projeté à Bégameni. Ce premier passage vers le
  monde parallèle n'est que de courte durée. Et ce n'est que le début de
  ses problèmes car sa femme va bientôt lui annoncer qu'elle le quitte ;
  son assureur lui annonce qu'il n'est pas couvert pour les dégâts
  constatés, etc. Rejeté de tous, il part chercher un peu de réconfort
  chez ses parents mais personne ne s'intéresse à ses malheurs et c'est
  là, en allant chercher du café pour ses frères et sœurs, qu'il se fait
  aspirer dans le sol et se retrouve de nouveau à Bégameni... où il est
  accueilli comme le libérateur tant espéré...

More or less:
The is a tyran named Zotan on a parallel word with 3 suns, a restoring paintor get into that world, accomplishing the prophecy and beating the Zotan.
From what I remember, he switches between the two words to get ideas (technologies, looking for historic strateges, etc.), and at some point after beating Zotan, get a "tyran" himself...
